# Archivo Sqlite EntityFramework

Tags: c#, sqlite

Estoy terminando un proyecto hecho en Windows Forms con `SQLite` y `EntityFramework`. Estuve todo el proyecto usando un `.sqlite` alojado en la carpeta bin. Cuando publico mi proyecto, quisiera que la DB se guarde dentro del proyecto y siempre sea accedida desde ahí. Aunque no estoy muy seguro de como hacerlo, este es mi `DbContext`.

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
    {



        private const string DBName = "Data Source = Test.sqlite;";


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {

            optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(DBName);

        }


        #region DbSets






    }
```

Comment: a que llamas "guarde dentro del proyecto" ? si pones la db como embebida como resource va a ser de solo lectura, es correcto como lo tienes la db como archivo va junto al .exe

Comment: A lo que me refiero es que me gustaría que la momento de publicar mi DB, esta pueda ser accedida desde cierta ruta. Actualmente se aloja en la carpeta Bin y el datasource apunta ahí. Yo lo que quiero es guardar mi sqlite dentro de alguna carpeta del proyecto y cuando le dé a publicar, se abra desde ahí. Se entiende?

Comment: a que llamas "cuando le de a publicar" ?

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres poder cambiar de forma dinamica donde se encontrara el archivo de la base de datos no definas fijo en codigo el `conection string` define este en el archivo de configuracion `app.config`

Agregar el archivo de configuracion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Defines el connection string

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDb" connectionString="Data Source=Test.sqlite;"/>
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Agregar las referencia a la libreria para poder leer el config

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usa la linea en el codigo

```
string connstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDb"].ConnectionString;
```

Pero como se trata de `Entity framework` podrias ser algo como esto

```
public class TestContext : DbContext
{

    private readonly string connectionString;

    public TestContext() : base()
    {
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestDb"].ConnectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite(connectionString);
    }

    #region DbSets
}
```

[Database Initialization in Entity Framework 6](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: Cuando me refiero a publicar, me refiero a terminar con el proyecto. https://i.imgur.com/kQD1tQ4.png Una vez que lo instalo, me sale la siguiente excepcion, debido a que no encuentra mi base de datos sqlite. https://i.imgur.com/yzyu4Oz.png 

Lo que quiero hacer es alojar mi DB dentro del proyecto (en la solución) y que cuando publique el proyecto sea capaz de leerlo ahí dentro. Quizás lo que digo no es posible de hacer, pero eso es lo que necesito.